# Is there a simpler way to create and buy/sell order with a trailing stop?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to build a very simply set of buy/sell commands with a stop loss and trailing stop. Is there a smarter way to do this?

```
//@version=5
strategy("Buy/Sell Order with Trailing Stop", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

strategy.entry ("L1", strategy.long, qty = 10, limit = 88, stop = 86)
strategy.exit ("S1", "L1", strategy.short, qty = 10, limit = 98, stop = 100, trail_price=1)

strategy.entry ("L2", strategy.long, qty = 10, limit = 86, stop = 84)
strategy.exit ("S1", "L2", strategy.short, qty = 10, limit = 96, stop = 100, trail_price=1)
```

Comment: What are you looking for to improve?

Answer (score 0):

For example you can add some `inputs`.
Take a look on strategies examples, e.g
https://www.tradingview.com/script/IHVPG6TS-Stop-loss-and-Take-Profit-in-example/

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Do you mean the Long and short strategy inputs. What if I don't have a strategy just buy and sell prices I input myself?